# Issue With BuddyPress When Moving Wordpress Site

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I just moved a wordpress site to a new domain using the following steps:

- Copied All Files From Old Domain to New Domain
- Updated DB information in the config file
- Searched and replaced SQL file for all old domain and updated to new domain
- Imported the SQL into the new database

Now when I try to access the site I am getting the following error

```
Call to undefined function bp_get_default_options()
```

I can not seem to find anyone else who is having this issue and it seems to be an issue with the buddypress plugin. Is there somewhere else I need to update the domain name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like a domain name problem, but a corrupt file problem.

1. Rename your buddypress plugin folder to something else. It will deactivate the plugin.
2. Remove the plugin from the dashboard and reinstall it.

If it doesn't solve the problem, let me know wich file is causing the error.

Comment: I did not know you could deactivate plugins like that. That worked great. I'll just reinstall buddypress now.